# Adding a details button to a dynamic HTML list

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html

I have an HTML list that is generated dynamically using filtered data.

```
<tbody>
            @{
                foreach (var item in listado.Where(x => x.Raw != null)) {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@item.Id</td>
                        <td>@item.Usuario</td>
                        <td>@item.NIF_CIF</td>
                        <td>
                            @if (!(String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Telefono)) && !(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.Telefono))) {
                                @item.Telefono
                            } else {
                                @Html.Raw("No disponible")}
                        </td>
                        <td>@Math.Round(item.PrecioTotal)&nbsp;&euro;</td>
                        <td>@item.FechaCreacion.ToShortDateString()</td>
                        <td>
                            <button id="detalles@(item.Id)">Detalles</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="vistaDetalles@(item.Id)" hidden>
                        <td>Detalles del presupuesto</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
        </tbody>
```

I've tried to tag the button as you can see using the item.Id and then point to it in this script:

```
<script>
$("document").ready(function (Id) {
    $("#detalles"+ Id).click(function (Id) {
        $("#vistaDetalles" + Id).show();
    });
});</script>
```

I've also tried not to tag them and catch all the buttons (removing the +Id part) and the same technique to catch all the hidden tds, but nothing works. What am I doing wrong? Also, can you recommend some learning material so I can get this part a bit clearer?
Thanks in advance. Regards.

Comment: your script is totally wrong for some aspects, remove Id from document.ready function. Replace $("#detalles"+ Id).click(function (Id) with $(document).on("click", "id^=detalles", function () {

Comment: That doesn't work either. I know I'm not pinting the buttons nor the tds right, but don't know how to do it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use data attributes for this purpose

**HTML**

```
<button class="detalles" data-itemid="@item.Id">Detalles</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".detalles").on("click",function(){
   var itemId = $(this).data('itemid');
   $('#vistaDetalles'+itemId).show();
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This actually worked, but only for the first button of the list. No idea where the mistake is, but thanks again.

Comment: @dCarMal, That is because the id must be going same while you iterate through. Change `id="detalles"` to `class="detalles"`. Let me update the answer in a moment. I forgot to visualized that

Comment: @dCarMal, Check now

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much, that solved the issue. Now every button slides the details field I wanted. Again, thank you and thanks to everyone for your support.

Answer (score 1):

I would replace your button with

```
<button onclick="detalles(@item.Id)">Detalles</button>
```

And change your JavaScript to:

```
<script>
    function detalles(Id) {
        $("#vistaDetalles" + Id).show();
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried it and didn't work, but looks promising. Maybe I have a mistake somewhere else?

Comment: Try to replace $("#vistaDetalles" + Id).show() with  $("#vistaDetalles" + Id).removeAttr('hidden'). But keep in mind that you are not hidding them once they have been shown. So if you click on details on multiple entries, they will all show.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:-

```
<script>
$("document").ready(function (Id) {
    $("body").on("click","#detalles"+ Id, function (Id) {
        $("#vistaDetalles" + Id).show();
    });
});</script>
```